# Fragments inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

Is there any help, resources, example or a tutorial available for putting fragments inside a fragment?

I have two tabs put up using Action Bar Navigation tabs, which essentially are fragments.  What I want to do is, put in a ListFragment and a DialogFragment (to display a view with details) in one of those Action Bar Navigation tabs fragment.

Possible??  Please help.  Thanks

Here's what I have done till now:

1. Followed Android's article on implementing navigation tabs on Action Bar and implemented a two tab action bar, this is running fine and I am able to show two different layouts.
2. In one of these tabs, I want to show a Fragmented view, for this I have created a FragmentList class with custom ArrayAdapter and data items, the data detail layout and class.
3. I am now stuck on how to display the fragments inside the tab. Following is the code which shows the content of first tab, how can I modify it to initialize the list fragment properly?

.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    View viewer = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.doodle_list, container,false);
    return viewer;
}
```

Comment: can you give us an example of your code?

Comment: I'm stuck actually.  I'll describe what I have done till now in my question, editing it.

Comment: No you can't have fragments inside fragments , bad things happen, puppies die

Comment: oh okay :) that's most helpful @Blundell. I can stop the ruckus now :D thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any help, resources, example or a tutorial available for putting fragments inside a fragment?

<strike>Fragments inside of fragments is not supported.</strike>

Fragments inside of fragments is supported on Android 4.2+ and via the Android Support package's backport of fragments. I'd still look to avoid it where possible.

> I have two tabs put up using Action Bar Navigation tabs, which essentially are fragments.

You chose to do that. There is nothing about action bar tabs that *requires* the use of fragments.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I actually followed http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs where they say I have to use Fragments.  Can you please point me to some other resource where I can learn how not to use Fragments and still be able to do this?  Thanks

Comment: @kishu27: " where they say I have to use Fragments" -- that's not a good bit of documentation, and I will file a bug report on it shortly. "Can you please point me to some other resource where I can learn how not to use Fragments and still be able to do this?" --  ignore the `FragmentTransaction` passed to the `TabListener` callback methods and do something else to update your UI.

Comment: @kishu27 As of API 17 4.2 Jelly Bean, you can do nested Fragments. Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) to Android Developers for nested fragments.

Comment: @CommonsWare there many articles saying about nested fragments .Even in [developer site](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

Comment: @CommonsWare check this out http://rootzwiki.com/topic/36433-nested-fragments-example-for-android-42-api-v17/

Comment: Neverthless, I'm staying away from nested fragments. Many issues. It works okay but not good for a polished finishing on the app

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. You can use Support library and ViewPager. If you don't need swiping by gesture you can disable swiping. So here is some code to improve my solution:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);
    final ArrayList<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    list.add(new TrFrag());
    list.add(new TrFrag());
    list.add(new TrFrag());

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            return list.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

}

P.S.It is ugly code for test, but it improves that it is possible.